# How to convert a 2d array in String to int?

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

My program is to input a txt file into a 2d array use to calculate and present some data.

my input file look like:

[Student], Exam1, Exam2, Exam3

may, 100, 100, 100

peter, 99, 60, 80

john, 100, 50, 100

I am new to java. After I input the txt file into the 2d array, the array would be in String datatype, how can I convert it to int type so that I can calculate some statistic like every student's average score, total score or class average score? And should put the calculation?

My code:

```
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    String line = "";

    /*Find number of row and column of the file.*/
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
      if (width == 0){
                  /*Find the number of row using split method(",")*/
                    String[] str = line.split(",");
                    width = str.length;
      }
      height++;
    }
    System.out.println("The text file contains:");
    System.out.println("Row : " + height);
    System.out.println("Column : " + width);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The sales figure of the company:");

    /*Adding values to the 2D Array and organize data.*/
    String[][] data = new String[height][width];
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int columnWidth = 20;
    StringBuilder format;
    int addition = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        if ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
          String[] str = line.split(",");

          for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            data[i][j] = str[j];
            format = new StringBuilder(str[j]);

            for (int k = format.length(); k< columnWidth; k++){
              format.append(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(format.toString());
          }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Thanks everyone =]

Comment: Integer.parseInt(String s) - that will convert your String to an int

Comment: I've added the `homework` tag, because this clearly *is* homework

Comment: Where should I put the statement to convert all the String in the array to int?

Comment: and this is why `fizzbuzz` was invented!

Answer (score 2):

Please use Integer.parseInt(String value) to convert string to integer

Comment: Where should this statement be? Should I use a for loop?

Comment: @Benson:  Right now you have a clear example of assigning each value to a 2-dimensional String array (`data`).  Declare `data` as an `int[][]` instead and when you assign a value to a position in the array use `parseInt` at that point.

Comment: Sorry, still not understand. When scanning the file separate, it is string, how and where can I convert it into int?

Comment: @Benson: Make an effort yourself, we're not here to do your homework.  Look at the line `data[i][j] = str[j]` and imagine how that would change if `data` were an `int[][]` instead of a `String[][]`.  If you don't understand how to convert a single `String` to a single `int`, please explain what you don't understand about hakish's very to-the-point answer.